# Can we see our future?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, psychology

Sometime I feel like these incident or moments I had spent before. When I visit new places which I never visited then also I feel like I had visited it before. I might have seen these things in my dream. Is this normal thing?

Comment: Off-topic, but yes, that's very normal.

Comment: AFAIK this happens when your brain accidentally stores information before processing it. (I'm not entirely sure if this has been proven or is just a theory.) When this happens, your brain finds a memory of it when processing it with obvious consequences.

Comment: Ha, I thought I added an explanation to my comment but actually messed it up: I meant "a memory of the events it is processing".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_vu

Comment: @11684 It seems that it's thought that familiarity is somewhat separable from recognition. Within this thoery it's not a matter of storing *unprocessed* data, but of only being able to *access* the data used for judging familiarity (it's likely that data for recognition was stored and then forgotten). Essentially, it's a vague recollection of places you've been, but have forgotten the specific details of (i.e. those needed to be able to identify it explicitly)

Comment: @Lucas So when I have a memory that resembles what I am currently experiencing, but forgot part of it, it causes Déjà vu (or whatever accents you should use)?

Comment: @11684 that's the gist of it, yeah. It's essentially just a non-specific memory. *"a strong familiarity signal can stem from a high degree of overlap between the elements of the current situation and those of one particular prior situation, or it can stem from more global familiarity resulting from a moderate degree of overlap between the current situation and each of multiple prior situations that have been stored in memory."* Such a theory actually says very little of substance beyond them being vague memories of some kind not inconsistent with the phenomenon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you describe is called [déjà vu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deja_vu). It is a well-known (as in: frequent) phenomenon. Whether it is 'normal' or unhealthy or a symptom etc. is not something we can answer here.

Nevertheless, to ease any worries:

> In a survey, Brown had concluded that approximately two-thirds of the population have had déjà vu experiences.

Comment: Also this is explainable biologicaly by the way short term and long term memory work

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any false memories?

Trick question, there is no way you can know, if something has somehow gotten the status of a memory in your brain it will seem as real to you as any other memory, regardless of origin.

A similar, but widely recognised brain defect is missing memories, commonly known as forgetting. Some memories disappear partially, we remember only fractions of a whole, some disappear completely, and some seem to have disappeared until we are somehow reminded of their existence. The matter is certainly more complex than some memories simply going away while others stay. It stands to reason that we have wast amounts of memories somewhere in the realm between remembered and forgotten.

Our minds are always searching for memories that are similar to the current situation, whether it is some place we have been, something we have done or some person we have met, we expect our memories to help us. Even if it is one of those half forgotten memories, what is left of it might be useful. Sometimes what we find isn't really coherent any more, maybe all there is left is a few parameters that by coincidence match the current situation. We didn't really remember anything, we just got the sensation that there was a matching memory. This might lead to concluding that the current event has happened before, which might manifest as a false memory. Most of the time we will probably never be the wiser, but sometimes we have strong proof for the contrary, thus a memory that defies logic.

It doesn't feel right to doubt ones own memory, but it stands to reason that there is no sure way a brain can detect all of its own errors, as failing the error detection is also a possible error. Sometimes we get a hint about our own fallibility when we end up with contradicting memories, but it seems reasonable to assume that it is far more common to gain a false memory that will never be brought in doubt.